# How to get the file path with the prefix file:// in android?

Tags: android, file, filepath

This will give me a file path like this:
**/storage/emulated/0/myimage.jpg**

```
File imageFile = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),   "myimage.jpg");
String path = destination.getAbsolutePath();
Log.d("path", path);
```

If I use this path to load the image into an ImageView using Picasso, it won't work.

```
Picasso.with(this.context).load("/storage/emulated/0/myimage.jpg").into(imageView);
```

It works only if I prefix the path with **file://**

```
Picasso.with(this.context).load("file:///storage/emulated/0/myimage.jpg").into(imageView);
```

Is there a way to get the file path with this **file://** instead of getting the absolute path and then prepend this manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`Uri.fromFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile(java.io.File)) to get [`URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) from file:

```
Uri uriFileName = Uri.fromFile(yourFile);
String uriStr = uriFileName.toString();
```

> Example: "file:///tmp/android.txt"

Answer (score 3):

Go Like this:

```java
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/";

File file = new File(path , "myImage.jpg");

Picasso.with(mContext).load(file).into(ImageView);
```

Picasso can accept Files as well. So in your code you are done at this point:

```java
File imageFile = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),   "myimage.jpg");
```

and you just need to put it in picasso

```java
Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageFile).into(ImageView);
```